# How to import a script into a react element and use the class and functions provided by that script

Tags: reactjs

I need to use this script < script type="text/javascript" src="http://ezwp.tv/Scripts/webService.js" >

I need to use it like this var x = new instance_From_Script("")

but in react it is used differently.

I have done this,

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "/static/libs/your_script.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded();
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

but I do not know how to use it outside of the JSX in the render () return ()

what I would really like to do is set an instance of the script in my states so

```
this.state = {
script: new script_instance()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With using that snippet, you can access any object in that external JS file in `global` object (`window` in browsers) after component mounted.

consider:

importing external js file using `componentDidMount` method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "/url_to_jquery/jquery.min.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded();
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Now you can access jquery selectors like this in your declared method:

```
yourMethodName(){
    window.$("#sample").click(function(){
        alert("Text: Button Clicked");
    });
}
```